# Почему вопрос закрыть легче?

Tags: обсуждение

Приведу [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/631413/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%8A%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). (То, что этот вопрос задан мною не имеет значения.) Согласно установленным правилам SO - вопрос должен быть полезен (как минимум). В данном примере, на данный момент, 3 участника проголосовали ЗА - значит, вопрос **полезен**. Тут же, на данный момент проголосовавших ПРОТИВ тоже 3, значит вопрос **бесполезен**.

Интересно следующее. За закрытие проголосовало 4 голоса, не исключено, что среди них и те, кто проголосовал ПРОТИВ вопроса. (Проголосовать ЗА вопрос и за закрытие как-то странно, но не исключено) Так вот, противники вопроса могут тут же закрывать вопрос, а те кому вопрос был полезен не факт "вернутся" отстаивать полезность вопроса, то есть открывать опять. То есть они не могут оставить свой голос сразу, заранее - " голос за открытие". Понятно, что со временем вопрос могут опять открыть, но ведь могут и не открыть, а на закрытый вопрос ответ дать нельзя. Выходит вопрос закрыть легче, хоть он и полезен для кого-то?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как для закрытия, так и для повторного открытия требуется 5 голосов (не будем рассматривать ситуации с участниками с золотыми знаками за метки и модераторами). Так что я не вижу каких-либо предпосылок говорить о том, что закрыть вопросе проще. Вопросы обычно закрываются и переоткрываются через просмотр их в соответствующих очередях проверок. И если кто-то посчитает, что вопрос не следует закрывать, он выбирает вариант "Оставить открытым". Это как раз можно считать тем, что Вы назвали *"отдать "голос за открытие" заранее"*. Такое действие, насколько я знаю, способствует исключению вопроса из очереди проверок на закрытие. И закрыть его можно будет лишь непосредственно через меню под самим вопросом. А если вопрос не обновляется, не получает новых ответов, то и видят его уже не так часто, как новый. Аналогичная ситуация и с переоткрытием вопроса. Т.е. тут всё в достаточной степени симметрично. Иногда вопросы закрываются и повторно открываются многократно. Недавняя истории на enSO тому хороший [пример](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/342440/revisions). А это значит, что переоткрыть вопрос не сложнее, чем закрыть его.